# Replacing multiple command text variables in OLEDB connection with cell value using VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am still new to VBA and am having a bit of difficulty getting this to work.  I have a connection in Excel 2013 linked to SQL with a specific script in the command text.  I am wanting to build a VBA macro that allows me set the date range that the script works on to a specific cell value.

Example command text:

```
Select [FIELD NAME]
from [TABLE NAME]
where [DateField] between [DateStart] and [DateEnd]
```

In the above scenario, say I would want to set [DateStart] = "E8" and [DateEnd] = "E9" how would I go about doing that?  Most of the posts that I have read have said to use a Microsoft query in order to set your parameters, however my computer doesn't seem to support doing it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use replace function since SQL query is simply a string expression for VBA:

```
sqlStatement = "Select [FIELD NAME] from [TABLE NAME] where [DateField] between [DateStart] and [DateEnd]"

dateStart = Year(Range("E8").value) & "-" & Month(Range("E8").value) & "-" & Day(Range("E8").value)
dateEnd = Year(Range("E9").value) & "-" & Month(Range("E9").value) & "-" & Day(Range("E9").value)

sqlStatement = Replace(sqlStatement, "[DateStart]", dateStart)
sqlStatement = Replace(sqlStatement, "[DateEnd]", dateEnd)
```